# Angular Running in Docker behind a NGINX Reverse Proxy 404

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I've been debugging this like a mad man and hopefully, someone can shed some light on this for me.

TLDR:
If I omit the try_files in the reverse proxy the app works perfectly though returns a 404 whenever the page is reloaded or a link browsed to directly.
If I include the try_files in the reverse proxy I get a bunch of MIME type errors below.

```
Refused to apply style from 'https://app.fwslift.com/styles.f078b28aa628841d3165.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

Refused to execute script from 'https://app.fwslift.com/runtime.4d85aaa8b193e87dd636.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

I have an angular app running in a nginx:alpine container with the following config that gets copied in at build (probably not the easiest implementation to get CORs to work but alas):

```
server {
  listen 80;
  sendfile on;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  gzip on;
  gzip_http_version 1.1;
  gzip_disable      "MSIE [1-6]\.";
  gzip_min_length   256;
  gzip_vary         on;
  gzip_proxied      expired no-cache no-store private auth;
  gzip_types        text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;
  gzip_comp_level   9;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html;

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;

    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://app.fwslift.com';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
    }

    if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://app.fwslift.com';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';
    }
    
    if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://app.fwslift.com';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';
    }

    if ($request_method = 'PUT') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://app.fwslift.com';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';
    }

    if ($request_method = 'DELETE') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://app.fwslift.com';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';
    }

    if ($request_method = 'PATCH') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'https://app.fwslift.com';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'Authorization,Accept,Origin,DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Content-Range,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,PUT,DELETE,PATCH';
    }
  }
}
```

My ubuntu host is running nginx natively and serving as a reverse proxy with these configs:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name app.fwslift.com;

    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name app.fwslift.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.fwslift.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.fwslift.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/app.fwslift.com/chain.pem;

    include snippets/ssl.conf;
    include snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

    location / {    
#       try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;

        proxy_pass http://localhost:5001/;
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
            proxy_cache_bypass  $http_upgrade;

            proxy_set_header Upgrade           $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection        "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host              $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP         $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For   $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host  $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port  $server_port;
    }
}
```

I've tried to link the MIMEs directly to each of these configs as well as a handful of other "Throw stuff at the wall" things.

Can anyone give me guidance on this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to remove the `=404` from the following line, like so:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404; 
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
```

this will redirect all requests that don't match a static file to the index.html. After that the angular router takes care of the rest.

Comment: Good eye! I'm sure I copied that from somewhere but will redeploy without it thanks.

Comment: Hmm seemed to have no effect. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

If you're serving the app completely from your proxy server you don't use try_files.

If you want to server the files statically that's where you use try_files.

Just remove it

A better approach for deploying your app is building it and then use the Nginx static server

Comment: That is actually a good fallback approach, thanks for the idea. Ideally, the plan is to have everything be able to be run from a k8s cluster hence the containers but just to get something working for this customer I might just statically serve. Thanks